# Xml Design Seems Like Dark Blue

Tags: android, xml

Here my problem is I want to change my phone white screen again cause its so hard to see details on dark blue screen please help me

Here my screenshots
**https://i.hizliresim.com/ROrlMG.png**

Comment: what is stopping you to do that? Change it's color

Comment: I have already changed its background color i also tried the change app theme color it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you enabled "blueprint" mode in the designer. Just hit the blue diamond icon and select "Design" instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my lots of time. How did i choose blueprint i dont know :) But finally i corrected thanks a lot :)